# Datasource data is not populating

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs

I am new babie in Angular (Currently using 14.2.10)
Need to make REST call and populate the data in UI. But I can see only header is populated without any data.
I feel some minor issue (Not able to figure out). In Developer console i can see data is populating. But not in UI.

Please find my html and TS file.

app.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  <!-- name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Employees"> {{Employees.name}} </td>
    
  </ng-container>

  <!-- position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Position </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Employees"> {{Employees.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- office Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="office">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> office </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Employees"> {{Employees.office}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- salary Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="salary">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> salary </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Employees"> {{Employees.salary}} </td>
  </ng-container>
 
</table>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';


export interface Employees {
  name: string;
  position: string;
  office:string ;
  salary: number;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Sample-App';
  li:any;
  lis=[];
  datasource: any;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'position', 'office', 'salary'];
  
     
  constructor(private http : HttpClient){     
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ea172973100002d001eeada')
    .subscribe(Response => {
 
      console.log(Response)
      this.li=Response;
      this.lis=this.li.list;
      this.datasource = new MatTableDataSource(this.lis);
      console.log(this.datasource)
      });
    
  }

}
```

Output :

[image]

In Developer mode i can see

[image]

Please correct me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. See here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsfkcj?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html)

It looks like you need to fix your dependencies. You're using Angular 14.2.10, but Material 13.0 and Material CDK 13.3.9.

#### EDIT

I updated the Stackblitz, before I was getting the error:

`Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

The URL you provided wasn't secure, so I changed from:

`http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ea172973100002d001eeada`
to
`https://www.mocky.io/v2/5ea172973100002d001eeada`

The Stackblitz works fine with the rest of the code you provided.

Comment: Hi Meqwz, i have updated "@angular/material": "^14.2.7", "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7", still data is not populated. When i hard code the data (without making REST call) it is working properly.

Comment: @Developer Okay, it looks like the problem was just using HTTPS instead of HTTP. See the updated answer please.